# Excel Macro Save.As Date

Tags: excel, date, macros, office-2016, vba

I have a `Macro` that takes my Master workbook & saves a bunch of different copies with different labels.

Example of section for one workbook:

```
Range("E1:G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "099 Commercial"
    ChDir "T:\Accounting\Aspen Pre-Payroll (Shared)\_Payroll Emails"
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 50
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "T:\Accounting\Aspen Pre-Payroll (Shared)\_Payroll Emails\099 Payroll Bundle CREW & EXP.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

So the label after the macro saves it looks like `099 Payroll Bundle CREW & EXP`
But I would like it to look like `099 Payroll Bundle 08-23-2016 CREW & EXP`
with the 08-23-2016 being the date located in the specific cell `=RC[-1]`
However, the usuals `" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & " & " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY") & "` will not work & gives me a compile error pop-up.

My knowledge about macros is limited so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
[ERROR it gives when I try to run macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQVmd.png)

Comment: try lowercase `" & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy") & "` and post the code that gives the error

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it so I had to add it to the end of my original post as an EDIT

Comment: ah I see .. then it has to be `" & VBA.Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy") & "`

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Application.Text` (replacing 'now()' with your date)

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "T:\Accounting\Aspen Pre-Payroll (Shared)\_Payroll Emails\099 Payroll Bundle" & Application.Text(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY") & " CREW & EXP.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: If I use this:    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "T:\Accounting\Aspen Pre-Payroll (Shared)\_Payroll Emails\098 Payroll Bundle" & Application.Text (=RC[-1], "MM-DD-YYYY") & " CREW & EXP.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False it just gives me a syntax error & turns that section of text red

Comment: It won't be able to interpret =RC[-1]. is the range dynamic, or could you specify it as `sheetname.range("A1")`, for example?

Comment: or alternatively, store the date as a variable and refer to it as `Application.Text(yourDate, "MM-DD-YYYY")`